# Copy files from Hadoop multiple directories to edge node folder

Tags: bash, shell, hadoop, hdfs

I have the multiple directories in hadoop as following

```
/env/hdfsdata/ob/sample/partfile..
/env/hdfsdata/ob/sample_1/partfile..
/env/hdfsdata/ob/sample_2/partfile..
```

I am new to hadoop and shell scripting and looking for a way to copy the files present in sample directory (sample*) onto edge node folder location and the files should be named as follows assuming sample is the prefix for file name

```
sample.txt
sample_1.txt
sample_2.txt
```

once the files are copied on to edgenode, location the respective directories has to be deleted in hadoop. I have tried using to list the directories using wild cards and then process these using shell script and cat command but facing issue no such directory found.

Comment: I guess pasting your code here will help others understand what you tried and using that, they will be able to suggest.

Comment: Do you have only one partfile per folder?

Comment: @Snigdhajyoti yes I am writitng to hadoop folder using spark. There will be only one file the other will be success one

Comment: recommend updating post with what you have tried as a starting point,  members are not going to write script for you.... basic understanding of how to bash out the filename change will be almost identical executing against HDFS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getmerge` to create one file from many

```
#!/bin/bash

dl() {
    FILENAME=$1
    BASE_DIR='/env/hdfsdata/ob'
    hadoop fs -getmerge "${BASE_DIR}/${FILENAME}/*" "${FILENAME}.txt"
}

FILENAME='sample'
dl "${FILENAME}"  # sample
for i in `seq 2`; do 
   dl "${FILENAME}_${i}"  # sample_1, sample_2
done
```

> new to hadoop and shell scripting

You can use Java/Python/etc to do the exact same thing